# can a compiler assign a value to a variable even before the variable is actually initiated?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, compiler-construction, initialization

I've just read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html?page=5 and it says:

> the compiler is free to assign a value to the singleton member variable
>   before the singleton's constructor is
>   called

I'm wondering if it is a typo. Do they actually really wanted to say: **the implementation of the JVM is free to** instead of **the compiler is free to**.

and my second question is that do we have this issue with C#/VB as well? (in which the ""compiler"" is free to assign a value to a variable even before the variable is fully initiated/even before the constructor function of the class of the variable is fully ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer the first part of the question is that you are correct, though this is more a case of sloppy terminology than a typo or a mistake.  (Plainly, the compiler doesn't assign values to variables ... this only happens when the code generated by the compiler is executed.)

A more technically accurate restatement would be:

"... because the compiler is free to generate code that *may* cause a value to be written to memory for the singleton member variable before the singleton's constructor has been called, and the constructed object has been flushed to memory."

This kind of thing is most likely to happen at the native code compiler level, when the compiler (legally) reorders instructions, or simply as a result of memory pipelining.  The Java memory model specifically allow this so that the compiler is able to generate code that runs faster on multi-core machines.  (The flip-side is that your multi-threaded code has to synchronize in the required way, or else it is liable to be unreliable.)

(It is also theoretically possible for the bytecode compiler to reorder bytecodes, but the chances are that it won't.  There is little value in the bytecode compiler doing fine-grained optimization.  Indeed, it can be harmful since it potentially makes it harder for the JIT compiler's optimizer.)

---

I'll leave the C# and VB cases to someone who is familiar with the specifications of those languages.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, allocating the memory for an object and calling the constructor are two separate operations. For example, something like

```
Object o = new Object();
```

compiles into these bytecodes:

```
0:  new #2; //class java/lang/Object
3:  dup
4:  invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
7:  astore_1
```

After instruction 0, a reference to an allocated but unconstructed object is on the stack. The constructor isn't called until offset 4.  There is definitely nothing keeping the compiler from assigning that reference to any variable it wants to, including a static member. The article is therefore correct.

I don't know CLR bytecode, but I imagine it cleaves rather closely to the JVM's instruction set, and I'd guess the same sort of thread-related caveat would exist for that runtime as well. It certainly holds for native code compilers.

Comment: I don't think that an analysis at the bytecode level is meaningful.  The real optimization (i.e. reordering of instructions / memory fetches / memory stores) happens when the bytecodes are compiled to native code.

Comment: @Stephen C: But since the spec says nothing at all about how native code is to be generated, you're free to imagine a simple translation of each bytecode into a few machine instructions, with no reordering at all. Since the argument holds for this simple scenario, that's enough to illustrate the article's assertion that such a thing can happen. The sort of thing you're talking about makes the phenomenon *more* likely to occur.